# How to Validate textbox so that I cannot enter zero as first digit?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How should I validate my textbox so that I the text entered shouldnt start with zero. I can enter zero anywhere else in the textbox...

```
 function checkFirst() {
    var text = document.getElementById('<%=textbox.ClientID %>').value.charAt(0);
    if (text == "0") {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I tried with this code but it shows JavaScript Runtime error is thrown. I dont know how to clear it.

If there are any choices in regular expressions too pls suggest me some.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JQuery` and `JavaScript` match function to check textbox value by using regular expression:

```
function checkFirst() {

    var text = $('#<%=textbox.ClientID %>');

    return text.val().match("^[1-9][0-9]*$") != null; //wil work only if you allow only numbers in your input, otherwise replace the regex.

}
```

You'll have to do the same check on server although. There you use `asp:RegularExpressionValidator` with same validation expression as on client side.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression to validate the textbox value -

```
^[a-zA-Z1-9][a-zA-Z0-9.,$;]+$
```

This will not allow 0 as the first character.